# Invoke crash the program some times

Tags: c#

I'm working with one timer and some times when I close the form I got a crash with

> An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object."

this is part of the code:

```
void _PersonUnlimitedTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{    
    if (exiting)
        return;

    string time = person.TimerTime;
    if (lblTime.InvokeRequired)
    {
        lblTime.Invoke(new Action(() => lblTime.Text = time));
    }
    else
    {
        lblTime.Text = time;
    }
}
```

and I also have this when I close the form

```
private void Timers_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close?", "Close Timer", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        person.PersonTimer.Stop();
        person.PersonTimer.Elapsed -= _PersonUnlimitedTimer_Elapsed;
    }
}
```

I have done the debug many times and the problem is sometimes, when I close the form the program already entered inside of this

```
if (lblTime.InvokeRequired)
```

so the program will execute this part

```
lblTime.Invoke(new Action(() => lblTime.Text = time));
```

but the form is already closed, leading to the exception.

I don't know how to solve this. Can someone help me? I don't want the `try catch` like this because it's bad coding:

```
void _PersonUnlimitedTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (exiting)
        return;
    try
    {
        string time = person.TimerTime;
        if (lblTime.InvokeRequired)
        {
            lblTime.Invoke(new Action(() => lblTime.Text = time));
        }
        else
        {
            lblTime.Text = time;
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Catch is only bad pratice when you use hide to suppress unknown errors. Here you know the problem you get and I think it is just fine using it. Accessing directories you have no privilege is another example of knowing/expecting an error and simply passing it by.. And you can still test for `'System.ObjectDisposedException` to make sure nothing else happens..

Comment: @TaW yes i will use the try catch thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will keep the try catch as i said in the topic

```
void _PersonUnlimitedTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (exiting)
        return;
    try
    {
        string time = person.TimerTime;
        if (lblTime.InvokeRequired)
        {
            lblTime.Invoke(new Action(() => lblTime.Text = time));
        }
        else
        {
            lblTime.Text = time;
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a timer that invokes the callback on a non-gui thread, hence the need to marshal back to the GUI thread. This can expose you to a race condition between the thread and the gui-thread.

Instead use the Winforms timer class [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). It will invoke the callback on the gui thread and therefore you won't have two different thread operating at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why `try/catch` is bad coding, but you could do it this way:

```
void _PersonUnlimitedTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{    
    if (exiting)
        return;

    // CHECK IF FORM IS ALREADY DISPOSED
    if (IsDisposed) return;

    string time = person.TimerTime;
    if (lblTime.InvokeRequired)
    //...
```

`IsDisposed` tells you if the `Form` has already been disposed.

**But** this is also not totally thread safe. The `Form` could be disposed between that `if` and your `Invoke`.

What kind of `Timer` do you use? `System.Threading.Timer` or `Windows.Forms.Timer`?

Assuming from the method name `_PersonUnlimitedTimer_Elapsed` you use a `Threading.Timer`. Can't you use a `Windows.Forms.Timer`? The latter takes care of invoking himself and should have these problems.

If you cannot use a `Forms.Timer` for any reason, you'll need to use `try/catch` in the end. That's not "bad coding", it's a good way of exceptional error handling.

Comment: i have already tested with that, and don't work too because some times the form only get disposed after pass that part of code, it just crash when i close the form and the code is already inside of `if (lblTime.InvokeRequired)...`

Comment: Is that what is appening "But this is also not totally thread safe. The Form could be disposed between that if and your Invoke." @René

Comment: @Mario.C So why don't you use a `Windows.Forms.Timer`? That would avoid these problems, because it takes care of invoking itself.

Comment: im using System.Timers; because my timer is not in one form is in my class Person and my class don't have win forms

Comment: I know i could use win form timers but my teacher don't let me use it, he said that i need to use system timer

Comment: I think i will let the try catch probably is the unique solution that i know

Comment: Yes, `try/catch` will be the way to go in that case.